# MIPS Any reason not to use li instead of lw for storing ints,floats,doubles?

Tags: mips

I see people using lw and li for the same purpose, of storing and manipulating numbers in registers. But which one is the most adequate, under what circumstances?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see people using lw and li for the same purpose

They don't have the same purpose.
The purpose of `lw` is to **l**oad a **w**ord (32 bits) from memory into a register. For example:

```
.data
foo: .word 12345
.text
la $a0, foo     # $a0 = address of foo
lw $t0, ($a0)   # $t0 = 12345
```

The purpose of `li` is to **l**oad an **i**mmediate into a register. For example:

```
li $t0, 12345   # $t0 = 12345
```

Note that the MIPS instruction set doesn't actually include any `li` instruction. It's a pseudo-instruction implemented by the assembler, which will convert it into one or more actual instructions (e.g. a combination of `lui` and `ori`).